# In Django template for mark next n elements

Tags: python, django, templates

I'm trying to figure out how to mark the next n elements in a list when a special element is encountered.

I have a data structure that looks like this

```
[
    {"type": "normal1", "text": "some text 1"},
    {"type": "special", "text": "some text 2", "length": 2},
    {"type": "normal1", "text": "some text 3"},
    {"type": "header", "text": "some text 4"},
    {"type": "header", "text": "some text 5"},
]
```

Where the types are intermingled and the length parameter is arbitrary for each special element. The length parameter means that the special node "owns" the next *n* elements. The difference in formatting for each normal type in non-trivial. What I want is output like this

```
<p class="normal1">some text 1</p>
<div class="special">
<h1>some text2</h1>
<p class="normal1">some text 3</p>
<h2 class="header">some text 4</h2>
</div>
<h2 class="header">some text 5</h2>
```

I can't figure out how to get the divs in there. So far my template looks like this

```
{% for line in line_list %}
    {% if line.type == "special" %}
        <h1>{{ line.text }}</h1>
    {% elif line.type == "header" %}
        <h2 class="{{ line.type }}">{{ line.text }}</h2>
    {% else %}
        <p class="{{ line.type }}">{{ line.text }}</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I can change my data structure if need be, so that the special element contains a list with the normal elements it owns, but then I'd either have to duplicate my code for dealing with different elements or do recursive templates - which I've read is a big no-no.

Comment: Nice explanation for what you are trying to achieve, `+1` for that .. There is no way to achieve from your logic . Why don't you try from views.py and pass to context ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem and get on with it I ended up defying the advice I'd read and use recursive templates with a modified data structure. There are probably several performance hits when doing it this way. It just doesn't matter that much for my particular application. I'll outline below what I ended up with.

New data structure

```
[
    {"type": "normal1", "text": "some text 1"},
    {"type": "special", "text": "some text 2", "nodes": [
        {"type": "normal1", "text": "some text 3"},
        {"type": "header", "text": "some text 4"}
    ]},
    {"type": "header", "text": "some text 5"}
]
```

base_template

```
{% with template_name="sub_template" %}
    {% include template_name %}
{% endwith %}
```

sub_template

```
{% for line in line_list %}
    {% if line.type == "special" %}
        <div class="{{ line.type }}">
        <h1>{{ line.text }}</h1>
        {% with line_list=line.nodes %}
            {% include template_name %}
        {% endwith %}
        </div>
    {% elif line.type == "header" %}
        <h2 class="{{ line.type }}">{{ line.text }}</h2>
    {% else %}
        <p class="{{ line.type }}">{{ line.text }}</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```